# Save os response as variable?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run the `dir` os command on python, and save the output as a variable, something like this
`output = os.system('dir')
 print(output)`
How would I go about doing this? I've tried using subprocess, but I keep getting a windows Tree Utility error

```
import subprocess

batcmd="dir"
result = subprocess.check_output(batcmd, shell=True)
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Any particular reason you need the output of `dir` command? the `os` module has `listdir` and `scandir` that will give you the files in the current or specified path.

Comment: Dalvenjia's comment is spot-on: you should be using python's provided modules to explore the tree and walk it. But I'm intrigued by the failure of `dir`. Can you successfully execute `dir` in a normal command prompt, outside of Python?

Comment: OP: Go for @Dalvenjia suggestion. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using **popen** method:

```
import os
result = os.popen('dir').read()
```

This is the simplest way to get this data.
I assumpted that you want to retreive string format data instead of wrap object.